# Dividing 1 by a huge integer

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, opencl

I have to divide 1 by a number X of more than 4000 digits that I have stored in a string and obviously this is going to return a floating point number.  I'm looking for algorithms to perform this division efficiently but I could not find anything that convinces me.

As a side note, I would like to implement the algorithm on my own without using a third-party library.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
The reason why I do not want to use a third-party library it's that I want to do this operation using openCL but without losing too much accuracy in the process. Therefore using one of those libraries is actually not possible in this case.

Comment: Well from a purists point of view you already have the most accurate representation of that number - `1 / <The number in the string>`

Comment: Wikipedia provides a great overview of this topic with a link to many third-party libraries, which you could study to gain insight into your own implementation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: Just do `quotient = 0.0;`.  The reciprocal of a 4000-digit integer is too small to represent in a `double`.

Comment: What do these 4000, (!), digits represent, a cardinal number? What sort of precision do you need in the result?

Comment: @Eric: IMO this could be an answer to the question, not just a comment

Comment: I need the algorithm to be as accurate as possible when making this division, so I need all the decimal's of the operation.

Comment: http://treskal.com/kalle/exjobb/original-report.pdf

Comment: Well there's no built-in type in C++ that has anywhere near that sort of precision, so you're SOL in that respect.

Comment: @Ignacio: in general, there might be an infinite number of decimals. You need to either decide on a limit or, if you need infinite precision, work with rational numbers.

Comment: 4000 is a strange number of digits. Any chance you could represent the digits in bits? This answer provides some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808485/division-of-big-numbers

Comment: @Grynspan: there's no built-in type in C++ for trees, ring buffers or TCP packets. That doesn't mean there aren't libraries that already do it!

Comment: -1 This question shows negligible research effort, and imposes arbitrary constraints (no third-party libraries) without any explanation. Some elaboration on *why* you're trying to do something this unusual and *what* you've already tried would make this a much better question.

Comment: I've given +1 to dan04, but "floating point" doesn't necessarily mean IEEE754. It even refer to normal form/scientific notation/whatever. I don't know whether that would be correct usage or not, but it would be an understandable mistake. A bit of work with an arbitrary precision arithmetic library should be able to generate a usable normal-form result, but there's a good chance that there will be infinite digits after the point, so there is no "as precise as possible" - a number-of-significant-digits cutoff point must be selected.

Comment: -1 Such a poorly crafted question.. tried to help but now had to retag the entire question because it was tagged as C#/C++ to probably garner more attention due to the popularity of those tags.

Comment: 4000 digits are very few compared to this http://primes.utm.edu/largest.html :D

Comment: @Nowhere man I know, but he doesn't want third-party libraries. So we're back to "nothing built-in."

Comment: For the "nothing built in" commenters - believe it or not, algorithms are things you can implement for yourself, and even answer questions about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are describing a special case of division, known as inverting a number. Here's a paper which gives a description of Picarte's Iteration method of inverting a large integer: http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~cgutierr/ftp/picarte.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/), it has no limits to the size of the numbers handled, and will obviously have insanely well optimized number crunching algorithms.

As for implementing it yourself, if it's not for educational purposes, I'd say don't fall prey to the NIH syndrome! And a Web search on `binary arithmetic` should provide a wealth of documents to start with…

Comment: Fully agreed. This looks a bit like NIH syndrome.

Comment: There's sometimes reasons for NIH "syndrome" - for example license issues. I semi-respect that Ignacio may also not want the whole of GNU MP as well, even if licenses aren't an issue - but extracting the relevant bits would still be reasonable, and looking at the source to see what algorithm(s) it uses seems like a sensible idea.

Comment: Sure there are reasons for NIH syndrome. But in this case, there are enough libraries that are open-source and use a license that doesn't restrict the closed-source code using it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) structure, it allows you to make a lot of calculations however it's only available in the .NET 4.0

Comment: I already have the number mapped to a string, and again, I want to implement the division algorithm on my own, without using another datatype as BigInteger, GNU-BC or GMP.

Comment: Why on your own?  Is this homework?  If you are writing production level code then why wouldn't you use an existing and well tested library?  This kind of thing is a solved problem. Also, if you're using .NET 4.0 already then it's not like you're importing some new third party library, it's already there for you.

Comment: Isn't BigInteger just for integers? I think he needs a floating point result.

Comment: It's not homework, I just want to run this operation using openCL without loosing too much accuracy. Therefore using one of those libraries is actually not possible in this case.

Comment: @can: The result is floating point.

Comment: @Ignacio: openCL is not C#. Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: @0A0D: 1/(a number with 4000 digits) does it make any sense as a floating point? BigInteger division will only deal with integers and truncate after the decimal point (MSDN documentation clearly states this), and EVEN IF you could perform a division with a true floating point, the result would be effectively 0 as a floating point too, it needs more precision, something like a "BigFloatingPoint" class.

Comment: @can: It says it only truncates after instantiation. It does not mention division. At any rate, it is all a moot point since the question has nothing to do with C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268345.aspx

Comment: @0A0D: I can't see ANY practical uses of BigInteger regarding this question. I was commenting on the parent answer anyway, not the question.

Comment: @can: I don't think you know what you are talking about from any standpoint.

Comment: @0A0D: let's call it "not understanding what I am saying because of not reading what I wrote" (or at least, I want to believe that way) instead of flaming, please give a working example usage of the .NET Framework BigInteger class that can help the handling of a number in the 1/(4000 digits) range.

Comment: @can: 1/4000 digit range makes no sense. At any rate, the BigInteger is an immutable type which represents an arbitrary large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds. Since you are the one stating that it does not work, I would expect you to produce an example. I also suggest you become educated on BigInteger at MSDN.

Comment: @0A0D: i know what BigInteger is and has worked with it before. I know big integer has no bounds, but how can you represent 1/(any integer other than 1) as an **integer**? The result will be a floating point number, and no matter if you present the denominator with 4000 digits with a BigInteger, 1/(that number) WILL be a floating point, which you CAN'T represent, and any float/double/Decimal representations will be effectively exactly zero, not 0.000000000... (as you are dividing by a 4000 digit number) I don't see how BigInteger helps the problem. You use BigInt for 4k digits, not 1/4k digits

Answer (score 1):

If your number X is an integer you may well not be able to do what you want. `float` and `double` are pretty much out; you'll have to use a `long double`. On some platforms a `long double` is just a `double`.

If you don't want to use a third-party bignum package (why?), you will have to implement the division algorithm on your own (and that is pretty much going to require you to develop a good chunk of a bignum package).

Comment: Not even `long double` has anywhere near the required precision.

Comment: @Jonathan: I agree. I assume he wants that for representation (e.g., output), not calculation.

Comment: I don't think he knows what he wants. He just mentioned openCL in a different answer.